# How to create a lottie animation

Tags: android, lottie, image-generation, dynamic-image-generation

I was thinking of making a new project and I want to create a website where we can draw some image in Paint and using that image we can generate some lottie animation.

so, for that I wanted to know the JSON for lottie animation is generated .
what is the login behind the lottie animation
and how can I give some Slight motion to images.
is there is some API's which I can use.

If any one can help we can colander and create a website or Android application for this.

so, for that I wanted to know the JSON for lottie animation is generated .
what is the login behind the lottie animation
and how can I give some Slight motion to images.
is there is some API's which I can use.